# Characteristic distance of integral by dimensional analysis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis

We have the integral 
$$
E =
−\,{1 \over \left(\,2\pi\,\right)^{3}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\,
\mathrm{d}^{3}k\,
{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec{k}\cdot\left(\,\vec{x}_{1} - \vec{x}_{2}\,\right) } \over \vec{k}^{\,2} + m^{2}}
$$

Could someone explain the following passage found in A. Zee, QFT in a Nutshell, 2nd edition page 28:

> We identify $E$ as the potential energy between two static sources. Even without doing
>   the integral, we see by dimensional analysis that the characteristic distance beyond which
>   the integral goes to zero is given by the inverse of the characteristic value of $k$, which is
>   $m$. Thus, we expect the attraction between the two sources to decrease rapidly to zero over
>   the distance $1/m$.
>   The range of the attractive force generated by the field $ϕ$ is determined inversely by the
>   mass $m$ of the particle described by the field.

I have not heard the phrases characteristic distance/value before and how do we deduce its values through dimensional analysis?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: It has something to do with how fast it goes to zero or something, but google doesnt find anything on characteristic values so this is unorthodox terminology.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you have an integral and you want to extract qualitative scaling information from it, the first step is to figure out a change of variables that makes all the constants in the integrand dimensionless.  Note that $k$ and $m$ have the same dimensions (in units where $\hbar = c = 1$), so we should define a dimensionless dummy integration variable $\vec{\kappa} := \vec{k}/m$ so that $\vec{k} = m \vec{\kappa}$.  Under this $u$-substitution, the integral becomes

$$E(\vec{\Delta x}) = -\frac{m^3}{(2 \pi)^3} \int d^3 \vec{\kappa} \frac{e^{i m \vec{\kappa} \cdot \vec{\Delta x}}}{m^2 (\vec{\kappa}^2 + 1)} = -\frac{m}{(2 \pi)^3} \int d^3 \vec{\kappa} \frac{e^{i \vec{\kappa} \cdot (m \vec{\Delta x})}}{\vec{\kappa}^2 + 1}.$$

Even without doing the integral, we can see that it only contains the product $m \vec{\Delta x}$, so it will evaluate to some (dimensionless) function $f(m \vec{\Delta x})$.  The function must fall off to 0 at large $m \vec{\Delta x}$ in order for the Fourier transform to converge.  Since it's dimensionless, we must introduce some characteristic length scale $\xi$ over which it decreases significantly, so that the function takes argument $f(\vec{\Delta x}/\xi)$.  (For example, if $f$ were a decaying exponential, $\xi$ might be the length after which it falls off by a factor of $e$ from its initial value.)  Comparing the two expressions above, we see that this characteristic length scale $\xi = 1/m$.  In order to be more precise about what it means for $f$ to "decrease significantly" over the length $\xi$, you'd need to actually evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

What he means by the characteristic distance is the relevant distance scale obtained by using values of other dimensional parameters in the integral.

Since $k$ is a variable and $m$ is a constant having the dimension of $k$, therefore a mass scale is introduced into the problem, i.e $m$. The final integral therefore depends on $m$, which is the mass scale of the problem, and since [L] = [M]$^{-1}$, $1/m$ is the characteristic length scale.

Now the question is why is the integral cut off at around $k = m$, The reason is that the factor in the exponential becomes large when $k > m$, and as a result the rapidly increasing oscillatory behaviour of $k$ causes cancellation further beyond $k$, and so the remaining integral goes to zero very fast.

PS. If you do contour integration, you will get

$$ E = \dfrac{1}{4\pi r} e^{-mr},$$
where $r=|x_1 - x_2|.$ As you can see the characteristic length scale is actually $1/m$

Comment: Could you explain how you read of the characteristic length scale 1/m of the final integral?

Comment: @kalle it is similar to how you define the time constant of a LC circuit.The distance at which $E$ is scale invariant for all possible $m$ is given by $1/m$ and therefore $r = 1/m$ is a characteristic length scale of the system in question.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, what precisely do you mean by the distance at which E is scale invariant?